# I need assistance in implement Laravel Vue Pagination package successfully

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pagination, vue-component, laravel-pagination

I am having problems implementing the [gilbertron laravel vue pagination package](https://laravel-vue-pagination.org/guide/quick-start.html)

I followed the instructions as far as I can tell to implement it, however I am re-learning javascript after 20 years hiatus from development, so I need your assistance.

This is the data I am trying to paginate that is posted using a route & controller in laravel using the paginate() function.

[image]

I get this warning when looking at the console to try and troubleshoot the problem.

[image]

This is my code I am using in my vue file.

```
<script setup>
import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue';
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { TailwindPagination } from 'laravel-vue-pagination';

defineProps({
    articles: Object,
});
</script>

<template>
    <AppLayout title="Articles">
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Articles
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                    <section class="flex md:flex-row m-2 p-2">
                        <div class="w-11/12">
                            <div v-if="articles.length > 0">
                                <div v-for="article in articles.data" :key="article.id">
                                    <!-- Add articles data here -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mt-4 p-2">
                            <TailwindPagination
                                :data="articles"
                                @pagination-change-page="getData"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AppLayout>
</template>
```

Currently the page renders as there is no serious errors that it points too, but the page links don't actually render the new page.

I know the "getData" for the page click property is not correct, but I can't find in the documentation how to correctly implement it, so I was hoping that someone could assist or alternatively point me in the direction of a similar package or tutorial that could teach me how to paginate in vue for laravel paginate() function correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing implementation of `getData` method

As per documentation of Vue pagination package

> We use the getResults() method to fetch some data from a Laravel
> application. This method is called when the component is created. The
> initial data could also be passed as a prop to the component.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help, I ended up building my own component & just using the built in pagination, but your answer was spot on!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I used the following code to write my own pagination implementation for vue frontend.

```
<script>
import { Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

defineProps({
    articles: Object,
    links: [],
});
</script>

<template
    v-for="(link, key) in articles.links"
    :key="key"
>
    <div
        v-if="link.url === null"
        v-html="link.label"
        class="text-gray-400 text-sm mb-1 mr-1 px-4 py-3 leading-4 border rounded"
    / >
    <Link
        v-else
        :href="link.url"
        v-html="link.label"
        class="border text-sm mb-1 mr-1 px-4 py-3"
    / >
</template>
```